# Grease pencil objects render green (windows)

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

I've been following a grease pencil tutorial on youtube as I'm new to the feature and haven't touched blender since 2019. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c57qq2nE3B0
I finished the first part of the tutorial and went to go see what my model looked like rendered. But It all can out green. The main box changes shade with light, but nothing else is affected.
[image]

I've searched for solutions, there is no tints on the objects, I don't believe its onion skinning cause I've scrolled through the timeline. There are no modifiers either.
I believe a solution for mac users was to change a viewport preference to no multisampling, but I don't have that option.
[image]

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your .blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Link to the .blend file:  
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Wvws2ylE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Wvws2ylE/)